# How to unpivot without losing data?

Tags: transformation, spotfire, unpivot

After I do `unpivot` to my table, about half of the data has gone missing. I am trying to `unpivot` the table columns, KI, S, SU, and H, but not all the data is showing.

I tried putting the columns to `Unpivot -> Columns to transform` and the rest columns to `Columns to pass through`. See the result below:

[image: Result]

Comment: Possibly, missing data in your `unpivoted table` is due to missing values in `original table`. You can check this by looking at your original table and see there are no missing values in the columns you're unpivoting.